# colorls not available on some terminal emulators?

Tags: command-line, gnome, zsh, gem

running into a weird issue that I have absolutely no idea how to troubleshoot (and didn't find anything useful on google) so figured I could ask for some guidance.

I have [colorls](https://github.com/athityakumar/colorls) installed and working great in `gnome-terminal` but I'm wanting to switch to `termite` and whenever I try to invoke it it just complains that it doesn't exist. Same happens with `urxvt`

I'm using `ZSH` as shell and the error message I'm getting is just: `zsh: command not found: colorls` but in gnome using the same shell it works perfectly.

Comment: It sounds like you have a different PATH in the respective emulators - is one running a login shell and the other a non-login shell for example?

Comment: Yes. That's actually it. I had completely forgotten that I set gnome-terminal to behave as a login-shell as it showed up as a step to install `rvm` (I think it was that one). 

Sorry for the dumb question >.>.

Comment: @steeldriver Please write an answer.